# Array to string conversion error in resource controller in laravel8

Tags: laravel-8

I am using laravel8. I created resource controller. when I am using get method for that then it is giving error.

My route is:

```
Route::resource('/details', [App\Http\Controllers\detailController::class]);
```

In resource controller, I have index method:

```
 public function index()
{
   echo 'dd';
}
```

when I run http://127.0.0.1:8000/details
I am getting error.

```
ErrorException
 Array to string conversion
 http://127.0.0.1:8000/details
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to remove array syntax form the controller name

```
Route::resource('/details', App\Http\Controllers\detailController::class);
```